# How to place images representing characters in a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am interested in using a custom made svg icons set representing characters in a webpage.

Imagine I have something like this, where each square is a SVG file:
[image: the images]

And, in JavaScript, I have a custom counter (or whatever) which generates numbers from 1 to 100 for example.

I want a function that places the corresponding svg for each character in the number inside a `<div></div>` for example:

```
//    The counter
function counter() {
    var number = 0;
    ...
    setInterval(function ...
        ...
        placeNumbers(number); // every second, it calls placeNumbers with 1, 2, 3, and so on as argument
        ...
    }, 1000);
}

//    The image placer
function placeNumbers(number) {
    //
    //    TO-DO
    //
}
```

...to make the webpage look like this for example (3 SVG files inside the green `<div></div>` tag):
[image: the final result]

I know how to code, just need the idea about **how to do it**.

I had thought about using a Map and link every file to a number character (`'1' -> '1.svg', '2' -> '2.svg', ...`)...

...or just an ajax call to get the file by the character's name (`get(someCharacter + ".svg")`)

I am not in favor of converting it to a font file, I would like to know a good (performance) way to achieve this.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

Just to clarify, when I said SVG files, I would change them with colorful PNGs or whatever, just want it to work with image files.

As @CertainPerformance suggested, it can also be a big sprite with all characters.

Comment: Performance is rarely a significant concern, especially when small numbers are involved. But you might consider using CSS image sprites, that way you only have to serve one big image, rather than 70 smaller ones (for example).

Comment: @CertainPerformance Good, will also follow your advice.

Comment: [This css-tricks link](https://css-tricks.com/pretty-good-svg-icon-system/) might be useful.

Comment: [An Overview of SVG Sprite Creation Techniques](https://24ways.org/2014/an-overview-of-svg-sprite-creation-techniques/) might give some inspiration.